# Javascript date(string date) - date() failing to show correct difference

Tags: javascript

I have a database utc string i am passing into Date(attrs.endDate) then subtracting current utc date via new Date() and I cannot get it to provide me what would be the correct difference for 2 utc dates.

attrs.endDate is always 8h utc ahead and i am getting the difference to then do a countdown but i am getting a 13h difference.

```
var totalMillisecsLeft = Date(attrs.endDate) - new Date()
```

Comment: If you call [`Date()` without `new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), it doesn't use any arguments. It always returns the current date/time as a formatted string.

Comment: Added the new, and i am still getting the hours difference from my local timezone instead of the utc date in - new Date()

Comment: The timestamp (retrieved by `.getDate()`) underlying a `Date` object is always based in UTC. If the difference in milliseconds is off by hours, it's likely that `endDate` doesn't specify a timezone and the browser is assuming one for you.

Comment: it is just a datetime field in a database that is converted to string and eventually passed into there so it is just a "4/3/2016 timehere" string. What would i need to do to prevent browser from manipulating that ?

Comment: Date being counted down to is 4/3/2016 12:25:30 PM (which was done with DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(8) in c#

Answer (score 0):

the second date is not a utc date but your local date.
you should use:

```
var totalMillisecsLeft = Date(attrs.endDate) - getUTCDate()
```

Comment: I am getting getUTCDate() is not a function

Comment: I'm sorry.. the method works on an instance of the Date object. try the following: 
var d = new Date();
d.getUTCDate();

Comment: I get crazy off numbers now instead of the 4-5 hours off due to it grabbing my time zone. I think this is because getUTCDate() method returns the day of the month (from 1 to 31) of the date object

Comment: Date being counted down to is 4/3/2016 12:25:30 PM (which was done with DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(8) in c#

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using moment.utc(mydate) - moment.utc() and everything worked perfectly... Still not sure why